# Javafx 2.2 - Dynamic table view - table data

Tags: javafx-2

Below javafx code is not generating  2 row and 2 column, instead of that it display 2 column and 1 row.

Logic of code.

Column variable. Add column with for loop to make table dynamic. Planning to add data with for loop.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class FXMLTableViewController {
    @FXML private TableView tableview;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        System.out.println(tableview);
        List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
        columns.add("col1");
        columns.add("col2");
        TableColumn [] tableColumns = new TableColumn[columns.size()];     
        int columnIndex = 0;
        for(int i=0 ; i<columns.size(); i++) {
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(columns.get(i));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){                   
               public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {                                                                                             
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());                       
                }                   
            });
            tableview.getColumns().addAll(col);
        }

        ObservableList<ObservableList> csvData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<String> row1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        row.addAll("d1");
        row.addAll("d11");
        row1.addAll("d2");
        row1.addAll("d22");
        csvData.add(row);
        csvData.add(row1);
        tableview.getItems().add(csvData);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove csvData it will work. do the following :

```
//ObservableList<ObservableList> csvData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ObservableList<String> row1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
row.addAll("d1");
row.addAll("d11");
row1.addAll("d2");
row1.addAll("d22");
//csvData.add(row);
//csvData.add(row1);
tableview.getItems().add(row);
tableview.getItems().add(row1);
```

Because csvData is an array and you are adding array in cell. I have tested it will work fine.